# How do I add a pre-event to a property get acessor?

Tags: c#

**Long Description**: I'm writing a basic search by filter function from an entity, so I can do something like this:

```
public Entity GetEntityBy(Entity filter)
{ }
public IList<Entity> GetEntitiesBy(Entity filter)
{ }
```

The problem is with non nullable types (int, float, etc), and I don't want to "force" all properties to be written as nullables. I want to avoid any kinds of rules (such as applying attributes or implementing my own get/set) so I can write the entity just as usual and simply use this filter function.

The code looks like this:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int EntityID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}

public IList<Entity> GetEntitiesBy(Entity filter)
{
    if (filter != null)
    {
        if (filter.EntityID > 0)
        {
            //Add criteria to filter by ID
            //In this case it works because there shouldn't have any IDs with 0
        }

        //this won't work because DateTime can't be null
        //I can't check the default value as well because there are some searchs using the default value and I don't want to ignore that
        if (RegisterDate != null) 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

It's supposed to be a simple equal filter depending on the values found in the `filter` parameter, but as it is now I don't know when I should ignore the default values or not.
I already have a SCRUD manager sort of class, so I want to add a function call to the class that it belongs so I can check when a property has been read/written to.

**Short Description**: How do I **add** a function call before a property's `get` or `set` acessor is called on a dynamic class? Is this even possible?

Comment: This is a some kind of interface. Where is your implementation which you have problem with?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy It's not with the interface that I'm having an issue, I'll add more details to the question to clarify.

Comment: Better, but still not clear what is your problem. If value is non-nullable, then you should use it for filtering, because entity has some particular value, and this entity is used as filter. Actually I'd use same approach with nullables. If property has `null` value, then you should find entities which also have `null` for this property. Otherwise this filtering will be non-intuitive

Comment: Do you mean dynamic as in generated dynamically from like a database or deserializer or the dynamic type?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy But if the value is non nullable, it'll be initialized as 0, and I might not want to filter by that value. If the code specifically sets it to zero, then I must know, somehow, that I must filter by that value. I want to add the function calls to the `get` and `set` acessors so I can save which values were modified by the user. Same goes for nullable types, if it's default initialized, I won't filter by it unless if it was set by the user.

Comment: @Danicco How about adding a new Parameter to `GetEntitiesBy` like `Func<Entity,bool>`. You can call it like `GetEntitiesBy(x=>x.Name=="abc")`

Comment: @gorrilla10101 Dynamic as in I will only know it's type during runtime. I'm creating a code library for all these simple searches with filters, since we have way too much entities and we're having to create these functions one by one for all of them (if I get this done, it'll save a lot of work since it'll cover most searches).

Comment: @L.B I think it might have an issue depending on the number of properties you're filtering by, but that's definitely an improvement of what we have so far, I'll try implementing it, thanks!

Comment: Could an event like INotifyPropertyChanged work?

Comment: @gorrilla10101 Yes, but for that I'd need to write all entities implementing that interface (and that'd become a rule that I'd like to avoid). I know Hibernate manages to do this `get` and `set` acessor functions (or something like that) for their lazy loading, and I want to get that and implement this filter as well.

Comment: @Danicco if you don't want to filter by some properties, then don't use Entity as filter